# mysql rand with condition

Tags: php, mysql

Could someone help me out with the correct syntax for this query please.

I have, `table1`:

```
id,   int
on,   tinyint - this can be 0 or 1
name, varchar(2000)
```

From this I am trying to get 10 random `id`/`name` which have `on` set to 1.

What query should I use?

Comment: Error was caused by "on" not being a acceptable column name for mysql I think...(Surprised no one spotted that!)

Comment: It doesn't matter. You should be using backticks to delimit your field names. Since you failed to show us what you tried so far, we had no way to guess that you were not doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name FROM table1 WHERE `on` = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: Ah!  I was missing the limit, also mysql doesn't like a column called 'on'.  Thanks!

Comment: @MRW: use backticks on WHERE on=1 because on is a keyword

Comment: What is a backtick?  and is their a list of bad keyworkds anywhere?

Comment: I ahd the same problem yesterday when I tried to call a column desc for description...didn't work...is their a list of bad words somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT id,name FROM table1
WHERE `on`=1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0,10
```

**EDITED:** as pointed out, column **on** could cause a syntax error without backticks

Comment: He is looking for a 10 space limit - otherwise yeah!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT id,name FROM table1 WHERE `on`=1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: You forgot the limit on number of results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `table1`
WHERE `on` = 1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 0,10
```

Use backticks to delimit field names. In this case you actually *have* to in the `WHERE` condition, because "ON" is a keyword.